# STAX to modify a nested XML with conditions and write back for Huge XML- around 6 GB

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am a beginner to java and have been working on a code to unzip a zip file containing around 100 000 XML files and then merging those files into 1 XML file so that I can process one file instead of loading these many files.
I unzipped the file and merged it into 1 file and parsed using DOM parser but now I need to modify this Merged XML file and then write it back in 1 file. I am able to do it using DOM parser and StringBuilder but looks like StringBuilder is not able to handle this big file as it gives java heap space error.

As I did further research I understood STAX parser might be a good fit to handle large files with better performance.

I have been going through multiple articles and tutorials but could not yet managed to write the code which can suffice my requirement.
So, my XML has multiple tags, after merging I have a structure something like this:

```
<Items>
   <Item >
      <Tag1>
</Tag1>
         <Tag2>
</Tag2>
            <Images>
               <Image>
                  <width>200</width>
                  <height>200</height>
                  <url>xyz.com</url>
                  <action>update</action>
               </Image>
               <Image>
                  <width>400</width>
                  <height>600</height>
                  <url>xyz.com</url>
                  <action>update</action>
               </Image>
            </Images>
   </Item>
   <Item >
      <Tag1>
</Tag1>
         <Tag2>
</Tag2>
            <Images>
               <Image>
                  <width>100</width>
                  <height>400</height>
                  <url>abc.com</url>
                  <action>update</action>
               </Image>
               <Image>
                  <width>400</width>
                  <height>200</height>
                  <url>xyz.com</url>
                  <action>update</action>
               </Image>
            </Images>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

My requirement is to check if width and height under Image tag is greater than some value then only take Image Tag else delete it from Images section.
Same way some other tags I will need to remove from the file and once all the processing is done return the whole XML file back with changes.

I went through many articles for STAX implementation but I could not get myself clear on how to access Image tag which is kind of great grandchild of root tag <Items>.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy using XSLT 3.0 streaming:

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="Image">
  <xsl:variable name="image" select="copy-of(.)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$image[width*height gt 100000]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course you could use any predicate here on width and height. The stylesheet outputs the image if and only if the predicate is true.

However, if you've got 6Gb of XML distributed over 100K files then I'm not sure why you're concatenating them before processing. That's going to be much more memory-intensive than processing them individually (which can also be done with a few lines of XSLT code).

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am not sure on XSLT, I am exploring this now. About concatenating the file, my system which is using these files have to first load all individual files and then start processing them so I want system to save some performance by not loading files separately but just load 1 Big file and in the same process I want to shorten the file as well by removing unnecessary tags.

Comment: I can not save the XSLT template in hard drive as I will be deploying this code as a plugin in external application. I am trying to create the template inside a File folder in my Eclipse project. I am creating file with .xsl extension, is that correct? I am actually getting error at the first line inside template: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:mode" is not 
  bound.
 - No grammar constraints (DTD or XML 
  Schema). Am I not taking the correct approach? I am very new to all this, please excuse me if its so silly to ask.

Comment: You're having beginner's problems with XSLT, and if you can't resolve them by following standard tutorials then please raise a separate question. Any XSLT tutorial will show you the basic boilerplate structure of an XSLT stylesheet including the namespace declaration for the "xsl" prefix. Please note that this stylesheet requires XSLT 3.0 which isn't supported in Eclipse by default; I think the only processor currently available that supports the streaming capabilities is Saxon-EE.

Comment: ,Thanks for the directions but I am right now on a deadline and as XSLT is totally new for me I will be taking time to go through it. Also not sure if my application would be in sync with the same. While I am going through it, can there be some suggestions towards STAX as well, as I am already working in that direction, it might be a bit easier and faster for me to get it done.

Comment: We've all been in the position of knowing that it would be a good idea to invest time in learning a tool that's better for the job than the one we already know, so you have my sympathy. But I'm not going to write 50 lines of code for you when I can do it in 5, sorry!

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay! its just that I am on a deadline and starting it from scratch is going to take me time. I am also not sure if my external application is going to support this all, though I am in parallel working on integration of SAXON EE in Eclipse(if possible, not sure),

Comment: I started with XSLT integration but getting streaming error that it does not support it, I submitted another question on the same, would be very helpful if you could provide some directions, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487745/sxst0068-request-for-streaming-ignored-this-saxon-configuration-does-not-suppo