# SXST0068: Request for streaming ignored: this Saxon configuration does not support streaming with Java

Tags: java, xslt-3.0

I am trying XSLT first time and using XSLT 3.0 which has streaming capabilities.
I need to modify a huge around 6 GB XML as per some conditions, I have configured External Jar **saxon9ee**(also tried version 10) in my project in referenced Library but it still gives me error:

Warning at xsl:mode on line 3 column 30 of XSLTTemplate.xsl:
SXST0068: Request for streaming ignored: this Saxon configuration does not support streaming

Is it not enough to run a project from Eclipse with streaming capabilities?

Below is the XSLT Stylesheet I am using by referencing it from my Eclipse Project.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:template match="Image">
      <xsl:variable name="image" select="copy-of(.)"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="$image[width*height gt 100000]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is my Java Code:

```
    import java.io.File;

    import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
    import javax.xml.transform.Result;
    import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

    public class XMLTransformWithXSLT
    {

      public static void main( String[] args ) throws Throwable
      {

        //InputStream i = XMLTransformWithXSLT.class.getResourceAsStream( "XSLTTemplate" );
        StreamSource input = new StreamSource( "C:\\Users\\abc\\Merged.xml" ); //$NON-NLS-1$
        StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource( "Files\\XSLTTemplate.xsl" );        
Result output = new StreamResult( new File( "C:\\Users\\abc\\MergedOuput.xml" ) ); //$NON-NLS-1$

        TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        //TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer( xsl );
        transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );
        transformer.transform( input, output );

        //System.out.println( output );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably a configuration issue of some kind: perhaps for some reason the license file hasn't been picked up. But there's also an issue using streaming using the JAXP transformation interface: JAXP specifies that your primary source is used both as the node matched by the `match="/"` template rule, and also as the context item for evaluating global variables. The streaming rules for XSLT 3.0 don't allow the global context item to be a streamed node, so this is at conflict with the JAXP specification. Saxon gets around this by providing a different `TransformerFactory` class for use with streaming, namely `com.saxonica.config.StreamingTransformerFactory`, which supports streaming but deviates in this respect from the JAXP specification. Using this also states a clear intent that you have a dependency on Saxon-EE and want to fail (rather than fallback) if facilities like streaming aren't available (for example, because no license file can be found).

Comment: its still giving the same error, am I missing something in terms of Configuration or coding?

Comment: For diagnostics, call `factory.getConfiguration().checkLicensedFeature(Configuration.LicenseFeature.ENTERPRISE_XSLT, "XSLT streaming", -1);` I suspect this will confirm no license file was found. This is probably a classpath issue. Getting the classpath right on Eclipse is a bit of a black art.

Comment: As an alternative to loading the license file via the classpath, try setting the property `"http://saxon.sf.net/feature/licenseFileLocation"` to the full path of the license file.

Comment: yes you are right checkLicensedFeature gives me error telling It didnt file the license file. But I think I have been in lack of knowledge here, from further research I see I need to get a 30 days evaluation license file or need to purchase the license. Also, 30 days evaluation file is not supposed to be used in production as it will have some restrictions . Does this mean If I want my code to be used for production, I need to purchase the license?

Comment: Yes, to use streaming mode in Saxon you need to purchase a license.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I will have to take this with the organization then.